# R Web scraping: Error when submitting form for website log in

Tags: r, authentication, form-submit, rvest

I'm trying to create a web scraper which will log in to a particular website. See my code below. Everything seems to work up until the submit_form function.

```
library(rvest)

url <- '*****' #sensitive project url requiring log in

session <- read_html(html_session(url))

form <- html_form(session)[[1]]

set_values(form, 
           txtUserName = "****", 
           txtPassword = "****")

submit_form(session, form)
```

When I run the code I get this error. Could anyone help point me in the right direction or come across this before? I'm new to R. Thanks!

Submitting with 'btnLogin'

> Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
>     Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL].

Comment: actually it's looking like you're trying to use a commented note as code.

Comment: Thanks, David! Which part of my code do you think? When I run the everything above submit_form there doesn’t seem to be an issue. I added that one comment just for this post.

Comment: Ok, then please excuse. The syntax looks a bit strange for me, but just because I never work in R.

Comment: Could you provide the URL for which you are trying to fill the form?